# Expo - android.colors is not a provider

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm trying to build a project in expo using expo rebuild.
I get this error though:

`Initial base modifier for "android.colors" is not a provider and therefore will not provide modResults to child mods`

I am trying to build a project with react-native-vision-camera using this guide : https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/

I am not totally sure if it's related to the vision camera module or something else. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that has this issue and finds this unanswered question, I tried looking everywhere for a solution but in my case it was very simple.

You just have to uninstall `expo-cli`:

```
npm remove -g expo-cli
```

Then reinstall it:

```
npm i -g expo-cli
```

And it should work now.